# Is there a way to plot every other row using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

So I want to create two separate charts using every other row, for example in the following table country alternates every row:

| Country | City |
| --- | --- |
| Canada | Toronto |
| USA | NYC |
| Canada | Ottawa |
| USA | LA |

I want to make a chart with just Canada and another chart with just USA, preferably on the same sheet.

Comment: How would you do what you want to do in Excel? If you can figure that out you can transfer the ranges to XlsxWriter. For example, XlsxWriter supports non-contiguous ranges, see the end of the docs on [chart.add_series()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series).

Comment: On excel I would be manually choosing the categories or possibly using a formula. Would it be possible to split a dataframe into two and then plot the dataframes on separate sheets, like one sheet is for canada and one for the US?

Comment: You could open the output from the dataframe in Excel, manually generate the ranges, and then copy those ranges to XlsxWriter. Alternatively, as you suggested, you could split the dataframe onto different sheets.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I ended up sorting the data by the column and just plotting based off the different blocks, thanks!

Comment: That's probably the best solution.